# Gssapi+Freeipa+Python. Can't find client principal. But it exists. Why?

Tags: python, kerberos, credentials, gssapi, freeipa

What I do first:

```
>kinit
Default principal: bob@R1.COM

Valid starting       Expires              Service principal
18.06.2020 18:27:11  19.06.2020 18:26:26  postgres/c1.com.ru@R1.COM
18.06.2020 18:27:11  19.06.2020 18:26:26  postgres/c1s.com.com@
18.06.2020 18:26:30  19.06.2020 18:26:26  krbtgt/R1.COM@R1.COM
```

Ok. principal for "postgres/c1.com.ru@R1.COM" is exist.

And second:

```
import gssapi

p_name = 'postgres/c1.com.ru@R1.COM'
name = gssapi.Name(p_name) #the principal for this service
creds = gssapi.Credentials(name=name, usage='initiate')
```

And I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "gt1.py", line 8, in <module>
    creds = gssapi.Credentials(name=name, usage='initiate')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gssapi/creds.py", line 64, in __new__
    store=store)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gssapi/creds.py", line 137, in acquire
    mechs, usage)
  File "gssapi/raw/creds.pyx", line 158, in gssapi.raw.creds.acquire_cred (gssapi/raw/creds.c:2051)
gssapi.raw.misc.GSSError: Major (851968): Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information, Minor (2529639053): Can't find client principal postgres/cu1s.rostelecom1.ru@ROSTELECOM1.RU in cache collection
```

Why can this happen? Any ideas? Please, I need help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing up two different things: client and target principals. Your credentials cache, listed with `klist`, shows that client principal in that ccache is `bob@R1.COM` while you are using `postgres/c1.com.ru@R1.COM` as your client principal.

You need either:
 - initialize the ccache with a key for `postgres/c1.com.ru` first (using some keytab, most likely)
 - use keytab when initializing credentials in your Python application.

For the latter, you need to pass a cred store reference. Something like in this helper code in FreeIPA: https://pagure.io/freeipa/blob/master/f/ipalib/install/kinit.py#_43

Comment: Thanks you for the advice!  Now I'm using keytab and it works.

Answer (score 0):

for the error:gssapi.raw.misc.GSSError: Major (851968): Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information, Minor (2529639053): Can't find client principal postgres/cu1s.rostelecom1.ru@ROSTELECOM1.RU in cache collection

I solve this problem for adding the krb5 file to under the path /etc/,you can try for this method.